# How do you subtract list a from list b in Python?

Tags: python, list

So I have 2 lists, say list `a` and list `b` where

```
a = [9, 8, 7, 6]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How would I go about subtracting the contents of `b` from `a`?

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? It is not very clear what do you mean by subtracting the contents.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Python and some stuff is rather confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function and it's feature to support more than one iterable (the following assumes Python2):

```
>>> a = [9, 8, 7, 6]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> map(lambda x,y: x-y, a, b)
[8, 6, 4, 2]
```

`map` applies the first argument (which has to be a function) on all elements of the following arguments. For example:

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> map(sqrt, [1,2,9])
[1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 3.0]
```

If you use more than two arguments, the function in the first parameter must take more parameters, because it is called with elements from each list:

```
>>> from math import pow
>>> map(pow, [2,3,4], [2,3,4])
[4.0, 27.0, 256.0]
```

The result is 2^2, 3^3 and 4^4.

The `lambda` in my example is just a shorter way to define the subtraction function, the following code would do the same:

```
def sub(x,y):
  return x-y

map(sub, a, b)
```

Comment: With my code a user will input a word and by using ord() I change and split the word into its individual letters and at some stage I need to subtract one dynamic list from another

Answer (score 2):

You can [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists and subtract the subelements to create a new list:

```
zip(b,a) -> [(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6)]

a = [9, 8, 7, 6]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]

print([y-x for x,y in zip(b,a)])
[8, 6, 4, 2]
```

If you want to change `a` itself use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) subtracting elements at common indexes:

```
for ind,ele in enumerate(a):
    a[ind] -= b[ind]
print(a)
[8, 6, 4, 2]
```

Or using numpy:

import numpy as np

```
a = np.array([9, 8, 7, 6])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

print(a - b)
[8 6 4 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[9,8,7,6,4]

t=0
h=[]

lenA=len(a)

while lenA != t:
    x=a[t]-b[t]
    t=t+1
    h.append(x)
```

Comment: How so? I'm still an ametaur and I'd like some feedback.

Comment: You don't use a while loop with a counter to iterate over a list for example. Python has `for` to do that. If you need the list index, use `enumerate`.

Comment: Ahh okay , thanks for the feedback .I tryed a for statement first to be honest , but in the end it wasn't working hence why I ended up using the while statement.